# Ordenar números primos en una lista

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo la siguiente consulta para ordenar los números primos:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ListaPrimos (n1 IN number, n2 IN number) AS
    primo boolean;
BEGIN
    WHILE (n1<n2)
        LOOP
            IF n1 or n2 =< 1 THEN
                primo := false;
            ELSE 
                primo := true;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Pero obtengo el siguiente error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "<" when expecting one of the
>   following:     ( - + all case mod new null             continue any
>   avg count current max min prior some sql stddev    sum variance execute
>   forall merge time timestamp interval   date     
>   pipe   
>   specification>

¿Cuál es la causa de este error?

Comment: ¿Por qué me da ese error?

Comment: el "menor o igual " es `<=` no `=<`

Comment: al modificar el =< por <= me da el siguiente error                                                        6/4  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
6/7  PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

Comment: @DavidEgea, no se trata de `echar bronca` como dices, se trata de **educar a los usuarios sobre el uso de las funcionalidades que ofrece Stack Overflow en Español**. Te recomiendo leer: **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). He editado tu pregunta, si tienes mas información que añadir, recuerda hacerlo editando tu pregunta. [edit]. Saludos.

Comment: @DavidEgea, por cierto, también te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta añadiendo información que tenga la(s) tabla(s) que usas en tu consulta - esto, para revisar los datos que están siendo operados. Saludos.

Comment: Simplemente , es un ejercicio que me ha dado un profesor, no uso ninguna tabla , sino un enunciado , que me pide listar el cuantos nueros primos hay entre n1 y  n2.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar la lógica que estás intentando seguir con tu código para crear la lista de primos?

Comment: @ElChiniNet igual está en ello y de momento puso `primo := true;`.  Le salió el error este que lo detuvo. puede ser xD

Comment: @lois6b, tiene lógica que sea eso que comentas porque el código no hace lo que dice más arriba (listar los primos entre dos números).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error de sintaxis.

El primer error es la utilización incorrecta del operador menor o igual

utilizaste:

```
=<
```

en ves de:

```
<=
```

El segundo, en el ejemplo solamente estabas evaluando la variable n2 y te olvidaste de n1:

```
IF n1 or n2 =< 1 THEN
```

debería ser como sigue:

```
IF (n1 <= 1 or n2 <= 1) THEN
```

Debería quedar de la siguiente manera. Saludos!

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ListaPrimos (n1 IN number, n2 IN number) AS
      primo boolean;
  BEGIN
      WHILE (n1<n2)
          LOOP
              IF (n1 <= 1 or n2 <= 1) THEN
                  primo := false;
              ELSE 
                  primo := true;
              END IF;
          END LOOP;
  END;
  /
```

Comment: haha no uses "creo" porque pierdes *credibilidad* (qué ironia, no?) y explica mejor por qué la sintaxis la tenía mal y por qué tu respuesta lo soluciona. Un saludo ^^

Comment: Muchas gracias. Lo tendré en cuenta. Un saludo!

Comment: de nada, ahora está perfecta :P +1

Answer (score 2):

Lo que parece un error tipografico, por el uso de `=<` en vez de `<=` para `menor o igual` , tiene más miga.

Ya que la expresión `n1 or n2 <= 1` la estaría tomando así `(n1 or (n2 <= 1) )`

y `n1` no es un booleano con el que comparar la expresión `(n2 <= 1)`.

La expresión correcta sería:

> ```
> n1 <=1 or n2 <= 1
> ```

los parentesis no son necesarios pero se interpreta como:

```
(n1 <=1 ) or (n2 <= 1)
```

Comment: De todas formas, para mirar si son `primos`o no, probaria a utilizar el operador de resto(`%`) y miraria si es divisible entre dos para asi si el `resto > 0` es un numero primo y si el `resto == 0` es primo

Comment: @geraniego, si no estoy arreglando su codigo. estaba solucionando su error HAHAH

Comment: yaya, yo tambien lo habia visto, solo comentaba una manera mas "eficaz" de comprobar numeros primos jejeje

Comment: @Geraniego si haces módulo 2 y compruebas que es igual a cero solo estás comprobando que el número es par, si no da cero no tiene por qué ser primo, solo es un número impar. Esto sin contar que el primer número primo es el 2.

Comment: @elchininet cierto es, me habia confundido jejejej olviden los comentarios anteriores jejejeje

Answer (score 0):

Cada **if** debe hacer su propia comparación. Ademas que se escribe "<=" no "=<".

Vale decir:

```
IF (n1 <= 1 or n2 <= 1) THEN
```

Espero que te ayude, Saludos y Exito! :D